# Error when unlocking BitLocker encrypted partition with dislocker tool on Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, windows, disk-encryption

I installed Windows 10 and then tried to activate BitLocker on one of my partitions. I did the BitLocker steps. I entered the password and received the recovery key in the form of a txt file. After a few minutes, I regretted it and canceled the partition encryption steps. BitLocker was actually not enabled on my partition. I also disabled BitLocker for that partition through the Windows control panel. Then I completely deleted Windows from my hard disk and returned to Linux (Arch).

In the first step, I tried to add my partition to the system normally with the mount command, and I encountered the following error:

```
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt:

       mount: /mnt: unknown filesystem type 'BitLocker'
```

In the next step, I tried to decrypt my partition with the dislocker tool. (I remember the password I gave when activating BitLocker in Windows, but I don't have access to the recovery key.). After trying with the dislocker tool, I got the following error:

```
dislocker -v -V /dev/sda5 --user-password="12345678":
   
     Failed to read in #3: Bad address
     get_eow_information::Error, not all bytes read: -1, -8 expected (2).
     Getting EOW information at offset c07c2000 failed
     EOW volume GUID not supported.
     Cannot parse volume header. Abort.
```

I even tried the usual ways on the internet, but I still encountered the previous error.

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/bitlocker
sudo mkdir -p /media/bitlockermount
sudo dislocker /dev/sda5 -u"12345678" -- /media/bitlocker
```

The result of the above command is also this error:

```
Cannot parse volume header. Abort.
```

I don't know where exactly the problem is. Because BitLocker was not fully activated in Windows and during the activation process, I closed the window and disabled the process. I even disabled BitLocker from the control panel. But I could not mount that partition in Linux. And now I don't have access to Windows to test again.

**Additional information**:

My Linux is Arch. I used Windows 10 for BitLocker. I don't have access to the recovery key, but I have the password that I entered during BitLocker in Windows. I have a 2 TB hard drive, and the partition that BitLocker was enabled on was 500 GB, and had about 300 GB of data (but BitLocker didn't complete in Windows. Only 2% of the process went through, and then I canceled it. )

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda5 of=/tmp/dd bs=512 count=2
cat /tmp/dd:

      �X�-FVE-FS�?�(V1��)NO NAME    FAT32   3ɎѼ�{���ٽ|��}�}��@t
                                                 Ht������}����;M����M�N��(N��x�y�z�       |�0|�
      Remove disks or other media.�
      Disk error�
      Press any key to restart
      �������������������,U�_�G.�SͶMx����R��ޏ��3�@�Z),!�p�/��qԋ�
      p�"��:S����ԭ�)~���Pa�:�����f2�A�����xIe�6��u�����^r`Uj������/B�oh���8~���!!]��fI�t�J
                  
                             y\��R�QD�r�E*6�x�^]k*
```

```
fdisk /dev/sda5:

      The device contains 'BitLocker' signature and it will be removed by a write command.   See fdisk(8) man page and --wipe option for more details.
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this issue by trial and error.

The issue was that my partition was not fully BitLocker enabled. Therefore, I booted a Windows DVD (7 and above) and mounted my partition through the terminal of the Windows recovery environment in the first step with commands such as `gparted` and `assign`.

Then with the `manage-bde` command I got a summary of the status of my partition that I had mounted, and then completely disabled BitLocker with the `-off` parameter.

The important thing is that my partition was only marked by Windows BitLocker and this operation was not done completely. Therefore, without having to enter any password or recovery key, I was able to restore my partition to normal state.

Comment: Congratulations on finding the answer. And welcome to Stack Exchange.